# How to get eNB id of LTE on Android Studio (TelephonyManager)

Tags: lte

Good day,

May I ask how to get the eNB id of CellIdentityLte?

Is there any way of getting it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I got it!

```
                    final CellIdentityLte identityLte = ((CellInfoLte) info).getCellIdentity();
                    int longCid = identityLte.getCi();

                    String cellidHex = DecToHex(longCid);
                    String eNBHex = cellidHex.substring(0, cellidHex.length()-2);

                    int eNB = HexToDec(eNBHex);

                    return checkValidString(Integer.toString(eNB));
```

by using this method...

```
// Decimal -> hexadecimal
public String DecToHex(int dec){
    return String.format("%x", dec);
}

// hex -> decimal
public int HexToDec(String hex){
    return Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for. I tested it and it is true. The output of getCi() I convert to HEX, the last two symbols are HEX value of Local Cell ID and the rest is the HEX value of eNodeB ID. For example 1046022 converted to HEX is FF606. eNodeB is FF6 -> 4086 and Local Cell ID is 06 -> 6. Exactly as configured for the LTE cell to which I am connected.

Answer (score 0):

just use:

```
identityLte.getCi() >> 8
```