# Is there a smooth way to get the eNB id of a cell tower in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, lte

im new to android app development and currently trying to get the eNB in Android Studio with Kotlin. Im aware of this solution: [How to get eNB id of LTE on Android Studio (TelephonyManager)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43152872/how-to-get-enb-id-of-lte-on-android-studio-telephonymanager)

However, if I try to implement this, my app just crashes and I get no feedback. Is there anything special you need to keep in mind when setting up your app to get mobile cell data?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide the code, and any error or stacktrace this produces when run?

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize a TelephonyManager from the Telephony_Service and by filtering for the different mobile net standards like UMTS (3G), LTE (4G) or NR (5G) and using the "`getallCellInfo` Method, you can get all relevant information from the current cell your phone is connected with. Here is the code:

```
val tm = getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
val cellInfo = tm.allCellInfo
if(cellInfo != null){
    for(info in cellInfo){
        if(info is CellInfoLte){
            val identityLte = info.cellIdentity
            val operator = identityLte.operatorAlphaLong.toString()
            // get more Information like mcc, mnc, pci, tac, ... //
        }
    }
}
```